# need regular expression for now(date) format

Tags: regex

> regular expression will valid the below strings.
>
> 1.now(today date)
>
> 2.now-1d(yesterday)
>
> 3.now+1w(add 1 week to today)
>
> 4.now/M(starting date of the month)
>
> 5.now/y(starting date of the year)
>
> 6.now-w/w(remove 1 week from today and starting date of that week)
>
> I need regular express for the above.

```
/^now(([-+])(\d+)(\w)(\/\w)?|\/(\w)|)/
```

> This is the regular expression i generated but it fails some words like
> **now-1d/2**

Comment: Please add some examples you **don't** want to match. Since all of those do match with just `/.*/`.

Comment: That's not valid, is it? `/` appears to mean 'round to a given time unit', and `2` isn't a time unit. So I'd say you're right to reject it.

Comment: @ruohola i already specified 6 types those types should be valid and remaining all will need to fail.
Rup yes my expression says now-1d/2 is valid but now-1d/w or now/w or now/M are valid

Comment: To make "now-1d/2" invalid, add $ at the end of the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Michel Butscher.

```
^now(?:([-+])(\d+)([dmMwy]))?(?:\/([dmMwy]))?$
```

This works for me.

Comment: It seems your regex could be simplified to `^now(?:([-+])(\d+)([dmMwy]))?(?:\/([dmMwy]))?$`